# duplicating php resources

Tags: php, mysql, resources, copy, duplicates

are there any way to duplicate the resources produced by functions such as mysql_query?

it may  sound dumb but i wanted to reuse such resources so that i won't retype the mysql_query() again and again just to use have a resource..like for example

```
$rsrc = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0,1');
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($rsrc);
print_r($rows);
```

when you fetch a resource, it's value will disappear (that's what i think)
what i wanted to do is to reUse it again.i even tried..

```
$rsrc = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0,1');
$rsrc_copy = $rsrc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when you fetch a resource, it's value will disappear (that's what i think) what i wanted to do is to reUse it again.i even tried..

What you are experiencing is not the value disappearing, but the result's internal data pointer [moving one row ahead](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array).

It is theoretically possible to move the internal data pointer around using [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php), but it is rarely practical to do so. I've never seen this used in a real world application. Rather re-use the result you fetched, e.g. by storing the rows in an array.

Comment: the problem is i have these functions..get_rows($resource) and get_cell($resource) that's why im thinking of reusing them xD

Comment: @kapitan then maybe you need to rewrite those functions. It's not a good idea to meddle around with resources

Comment: yup i shud rewrite mysql::select() then it would return an array already instead of a resource..or maybe i could make returning a resource as an optional parameter thanks :)

Comment: @kapitan querying resources has the advantage that you can pull through huge amounts of data without reaching the memory limit. (If you fetch a million records into an array, it will cost your script that amount of memory. Fetching them from a mySQL result set one by one won't.) But usually, you use a result only in one direction, fetching one record after another. It shouldn't be necessary to "rewind"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reuse the resource.  You can reuse the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Put the result in an array and use it as many times as you like.

```
$results = array();
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * from ...");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
  $results[] = $row;
}

// use the $results array
```

Comment: i already have those functions..get_rows and get_cell the problem is they both use the param $resource

Comment: in that case, i think Pekka's answer should suffice.

Comment: @kapitanluffy it doesn't matter that they use `$resource`. You will be able to use `$results` afterwards, you won't need `$resource` any more